# How to configure Automated Code Backups at Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have migrated my website from Old Server ([HostGator](https://www.hostgator.in/)) to Amazon EC2 and its working fine since last 1 month, One thing I missed at EC2 i.e Automated Code backups as on HostGator it used to happen everyday, but I am not able to do same thing at EC2.

Can somebody help me in setting up Automated code backup at EC2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to backup source code you can create an S3 bucket and use the aws cli to sync your code directory to it, or write a small script to zip and copy it to S3. If you need an instance backup AWS [Lifecycle Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/07/introducing-amazon-data-lifecycle-manager-for-ebs-snapshots/) which you can have it take snapshots of your instance on a schedule and it will keep the past X snapshots allowing you to restore your EC2 instance to a previous snapshot if needed.

Comment: Can you pls share a tutorial from which I can learn How script can be created to backup code in the S3?